# AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR in SIlverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis, silverlight-3.0, directory

I have few directories in my IIS server (physical location inetpub\wwwroot\SampleApp)

The directories contain .jpeg images. I am iterating these images in C# from Silverlight.

And this is how I assign the image on the server to my Image placeholder in SL

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.UriSource = new Uri(url + sharedLink + currentSlide + ".jpg");
PresentationImage.Source = bi;
```

where PresentationImage is the container for Images.

Now, when I can access some of the directories and iterate through the images however for some of the directories I am getting this error `Failed to open System.Exception: AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR`

I couldn't find any helpful links on GOOGLE either. I cannot get a hang of this error.

Can anyone please give me a lead into whats happening?

Comment: There is a similar question here (which is not active now though) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355070/unable-to-load-an-external-image-in-silverlight-ag-e-network-error-exception                           However, the workaround cannot be implied in my case :( And moreover, it works for few directories, so I guess there shall be some security issue which I might be missing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error and saw the above link which also didn't work. Turned out the path to my .xap file was incorrect in my webpage. Instead of "/MyApp.xap" I needed "MyApp.xap" because of the way I had deployed it. "File does not exist" as an error description would have made a lot more sense!

Suggest checking exactly what filepath is being generated at runtime.

Comment: What if I used the same path twice and in the first time it plays but in the second no !

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and everything was OK but images wont load and than I changed the default start up project from the silverlight control to the `.web` project and it started working I don't know why but it solved my problem.