# wp7 image control not able to load image from url (AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am facing very strange problem with wp7 image control, it can load a png image from a url but unable to load a jpg image from same url.
This works

```
<Image Source ="http://admin.surveyanalytics.com/userimages/sub-2/1517491/180_60_logo.png"/>
```

But this doesn't work

```
<Image Source ="http://admin.surveyanalytics.com/userimages/sub-2/1517491/forumlogo.jpg"/>
```

I can see both image in browser.
In the second code **ImageFailed** event is fired with "AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR" error

Same is the case with windows-8 phone.

can anyone suggest me what is the problem. Your support will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you resolved this?  I'm running into the same issue in my wp7 app.

Answer (score 1):

You could be facing the same problem (with solution) here: [AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR in SIlverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624816/ag-e-network-error-in-silverlight)

Also check out the solution reported in [Silverlight and the AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR - a thrilling story!](http://www.primordialcode.com/index.php/2009/12/07/silverlight-ag_e_network_error-thrilling-story/)

Comment: the links shared by didn't help at all.